# Simpler arithmetic

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

In Clojurescript I am doing a minus - taking one number from another:

```
(let [external-take-central (- external-val central-y)
      _ (log "Ans: " external-take-central " from " external-val " take " central-y)
```

The output from this can involve quite a lot of unnecessary decimal places:

```
Ans: 0.10000000000000142 from 21.1 take 21
```

`rationalize` does not exist on Clojurescript, and nor does `BigDecimal`.

What is the best way to deal sensibly with these floating-point arithmetic errors in the Javascript execution environment?

In this case I would like `external-take-central` itself to not be slightly bigger/smaller than 0.1. I would like to find a generic way to make calculations accurate and easy to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use the value. You can use available javascript libraries and functions. In general, I tend ot look at the google closure library before considering loading a separate library as you avoid issues with having to define externs etc.

One possible solution would be to use the google.string lib i.e.

```
(ns ....
  (:require [google.string :as gstr]))

(gstr/format "%.2f" value)
```

or something similar should work to format your value as a string with just 2 decimal places.

EDIT: Adding some more information based on comment and to clarify some points.

Note that Clojurescript numbers are just javascript numbers and can be used in any javascript function which accepts a number. So, for example you can just do

```
(.round js/Math 3.00001)
```

or even

```
(.toFixed 3.0002 2)
```

or something more complex depending on what your requirements are. I would be wary of rounding/truncating at every calculation step. There are some cases where this might make sense (for example, you might want to restrict money calculations to 2 decimal places), but in other caes, you will just increase the amount of rounding error by doing this. For thigs like delaing with currency, I would tend to use either a clojurescript or a javascript library written for that purpose.

Comment: After a general way of doing calculations. Always rounding the result of every calculation to say 10 decimal places would achieve this. That is what I will end up doing unless something smarter turns up here. One calculation will feed into another and correcting the problem every time as soon as it occurs makes sense. I want the answer to be correct, rather than the output to the user to be correct. I only logged so that the number could be easily seen - for debugging purposes.